# What is the probability that a random integer is greater than $n$?

Tags: probability

As a countably infinite set, all infinite subsets of the integers should have equal cardinality. Because of this, I was wondering what the probability of a random number being larger than $n$ was? For example, if $n=0$, intuitively, it would make sense to assume that the probability is 50%, since there are equal number of numbers both above and below zero. However, the same is actually still true for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Would the probability for any $n$ still be 50%?

Comment: What probability distribution on the integers do you have in mind? The answer will depend on that. Note that there is no uniform distribution.

Comment: Yes, it will be 1/2. But probability that a random integer is divisible by 2 is $1/2$ and by 3 - $1/3$ despite equal cardinalities.

Answer (score 1):

since, as  André remarked, there is no uniform distribution on $\mathbb{Z}$, you can instead look at a sequence of increasingly attenuated uniform distributions on finite subsets $[-k,+k]$. you then have
$$
p_k=\max(0,\frac{k-n-1}{2k+1})
$$
in this case
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} p_k = \frac12
$$
as your intuition required